# How to create hide/unhide button in greasemonkey

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I am trying to create a gresaemonkey script to hide and hide / unhide a jquery window through a button.

Can anyone suggest how do I achieve that?

my current greasemonkey code is as per below.

http://pastebin.com/yLPPvspw

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<button>hide/show</button>').appendTo('body').click(function() {
    $('#draggableDiv').toggle();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MtLXd/)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that.

I can see that works perfectly on a normal Javascript evironment.

But it doesn't seem to be working in GreaseMonkey.

Any Idea why?

Comment: @Hutan Rimba You should explain in detail what you mean by "doesn't seem to be working". Did you see any error in console? Did the button appear? If yes, did the button respond to click? Again, any error in console? Better yet, you can provide a link to the page you are working with, or even attach a screenshot.